# Add Matrix to multiline Header in R

Tags: r, header, matrix, multiline, fixed-width

I've got a headerfile with exactly 4 rows in a fixed width format (saved with the write.matrix function from the MASS package).

Now I want to create a new Matrix with the headerfile I created above. Is it possible in R to add a fixed multiline header (e.g. as "text") to a matrix?

An example: I've got a header like

```
AB
CDEF 123456
GHIJK 789     101112
LMNOP
```

And then I want to create a matrix with date in first column and then the data (from another file) in the second column like

```
892201 0.1
892202 0.8
```

and so on. Note: It has to be the described format, because the program just read the fixed width format explained above.

Comment: I would be useful to see the code used to produce the header. I have assumed that the header is **exactly** as you show in the Question, copied and pasted that into my file and then run the code I show in my Answer against that file.

Comment: The header is progammed with the readLines(textConnection)) function. The code is like this: fmtlines <- readLines(textConnection("..."))

Comment: I meant show the code you used to create it (the code using `write.matrix()`). Anyway, doesn't matter now if my Answer helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the second set of data into the existing file using the `write.table()` function with the `append = TRUE` argument.

If I have file `foo.txt` with the header you show, then I can add some dates and other data to that file by first creating the data object I want to append:

```
dat <- data.frame(dates = Sys.Date() + 0:4, data = seq(0.1, 0.5, by = 0.1))

> dat
       dates data
1 2012-06-12  0.1
2 2012-06-13  0.2
3 2012-06-14  0.3
4 2012-06-15  0.4
5 2012-06-16  0.5
```

The the following will append `dat` without any extraneous headers or row names on to the existing header file

```
write.table(dat, "foo.txt", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

`foo.txt` now looks like this:

```
$ cat foo.txt
AB
CDEF 123456
GHIJK 789     101112
LMNOP
2012-06-12 0.1
2012-06-13 0.2
2012-06-14 0.3
2012-06-15 0.4
2012-06-16 0.5
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. I didn't really understand how the "append" function works. Thanks!!

Comment: @user1439894 You are welcome. If you are happy with the Answer, consider accepting it so others know this problem was solved successfully and to improve the overall SO resource. See the How To Ask section of the FAQ for further info: [faq#howtoask]

Comment: Yes of course. Sorry, I'm new to this, so I didn't know this feature.

Comment: @user1439894 No need to apologise and no obligation to accept an Answer anywhere on SO. Only do so when an Answer really helped. You can wait a few days if you wish to see if you get other, better Answers, etc. You can even change your mind if a better one comes along later.